# Ubuntu 14.04 - Hp pavillion dv5-2239la Can´t load Webpages

Tags: networking, wireless, firefox, cinnamon

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop, (Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon x64)

Now, im conected to my router via an access point to amplify area on my house.

Note: Ubuntu works well conected directly to the Router.

So, when i try to load any webpage Firefox (Try´s to connect) but won´t have response from webpage.

The notification area icon marks good signal and no problems.

I think could be a Proxy, IP, DCHP, problem but i dont know hot to diagnosticate IT.

Any Idea?

`ifconfig` Output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:31:50:86:8c:d0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12316 (12.3 KB)  TX bytes:12316 (12.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr cc:52:af:10:27:41  
          inet addr:192.168.1.71  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ce52:afff:fe10:2741/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:401
          TX packets:119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13810 (13.8 KB)  TX bytes:17291 (17.2 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:d3:8d:04:50:50  
          inet addr:192.168.1.68  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7ad3:8dff:fe04:5050/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14959 (14.9 KB)  TX bytes:14934 (14.9 KB)
```

---

> nm-tool

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan1  [INFINITUM0E037B automática] ---------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rt2800usb
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        78:D3:8D:04:50:50

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           58 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    f24418:          Infra, D8:97:BA:DB:0B:C8, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    f24418:          Infra, 14:CC:20:54:A8:4E, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    INFINITUM8331:   Infra, 00:24:56:9C:07:39, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 62 WEP
    INFINITUM0E037B: Infra, 30:91:8F:0E:03:7B, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA WPA2
    *INFINITUM0E037B:Infra, C4:05:28:8D:AC:96, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 79 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.68
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254


- Device: wlan0  [Auto INFINITUM0E037B] ----------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        CC:52:AF:10:27:41

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           52 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    f24418:          Infra, D8:97:BA:DB:0B:C8, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44 WPA WPA2
    f24418:          Infra, 14:CC:20:54:A8:4E, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA WPA2
    INFINITUM8331:   Infra, 00:24:56:9C:07:39, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WEP
    *INFINITUM0E037B:Infra, C4:05:28:8D:AC:96, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.71
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        64:31:50:86:8C:D0

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

> nmcli con status

```
NAME                      UUID                                   DEVICES    DEFAULT  VPN   MASTER-PATH                                 
Auto INFINITUM0E037B      f6f68a63-9e7d-43d0-8097-efcd0ccc230e   wlan0      yes      no    --                                          
INFINITUM0E037B automática b77b039c-43e6-48ad-b0e6-168199a4d6ef   wlan1      no       no    --
```

> ifconfig  output with Ralink Unplugged & Changes

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:31:50:86:8c:d0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:621217 (621.2 KB)  TX bytes:621217 (621.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr cc:52:af:10:27:41  
          inet addr:192.168.1.71  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ce52:afff:fe10:2741/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:5959
          TX packets:1327 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:62939 (62.9 KB)  TX bytes:169691 (169.6 KB)
          Interrupt:17
```

Comment: Please add to your question the output of running `ifconfig` from the terminal..

Comment: Sure, thanks, i hope it help, now is in the question.

Comment: Run `sudo ifdown wlan1` and then try to browse again.

Comment: It gives--> ifdown: interface wlan1 not configured, and firefox won´t load pages.

Comment: Ok. Please add the output of `nm-tool`

Comment: Thnks, I posted the output of nm-tool, in the question :)

Comment: Please add the output of `nmcli con status`

Comment: I just, updated the nmcli con status, thanks again,sorry for the late response, by the same problem im switching files to get terminal outputs posted here @_@

Comment: No problem..run `echo -e '\n[keyfile]\nunmanaged-devices=mac:CC:52:AF:10:27:41' | sudo tee -a /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, then `sudo service network-manager restart`. After that try to browse..

Comment: Thnks, they works now with my [Ralink 802.11 usb wireless], but the list of avaiable connections in [Broadcom BCM4313 802.11 b/g/n] disapeared (it reads: not configured)

Comment: I have both Ralink and Broadcom Internal connected for all of this process and terminal outputs.

Comment: you need to pick one..you can either USB or built-in but not both..if you try to use both a collision will occur and an undesired situation will happen where the kernel simply pick one as default..

Comment: Ok , now i can't activate the Integrated Broadcom, even if i unplug the ralink usb, how can i choose the Broadcom by default or activate it?

Comment: Please wait..i am giving you a compact solutuion

Comment: Note: I tried to run  echo -e '\n[keyfile]\nunmanaged-devices=mac:78:d3:8d:04:50:50' | sudo tee -a /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf    --------- with MAC AD changed to broadcom adress and activate the list of aviable consctions but wont load the pages

Comment: Please don't do anything by yourself unless you are sure of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have two adapters for Wireless (one built-in and one USB) and they both are being active at the same time, you need to choose any one of those at a given time.

As we have already marked the built-in adapter as unmanaged to get to the root of the problem by the following commands:

```
echo -e '\n[keyfile]\nunmanaged-devices=mac:CC:52:AF:10:27:41' | sudo tee -a /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now at first we need to reactivate the built-in adapter (or any other previously marked as unmanaged) as manageable by `network-manager` by following command:

```
sudo sed -i -e '/keyfile/d' -e '/unmanaged/d' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now as all of the devices are usable, if you don't connect the USB adapter then the built-in one will be used and you don't have to change anything.

If you connect the USB adapter then we can assume that you want to use it turning the built-in one off. To disable the built-in adapter run the following command:

```
sudo nmcli con down uuid "f6f68a63-9e7d-43d0-8097-efcd0ccc230e"
```

Now when you are done with using the USB adapter you need to issue the following command to enable built-in one again:

```
sudo nmcli con up uuid "f6f68a63-9e7d-43d0-8097-efcd0ccc230e"
```

Remember the built-in one will be automatically started upon reboot.

Comment: The first command works well with Usb Ralink, but when i run the second to Reactivate the built-in the webpages won't LOAD, i unpluged the usb and tried to browse with built-in broadcom activated but return to the frist problem, the pages wont load.

Comment: Run the two commands in the second (`sudo sed ....` ) portion. Now disconnect the USB, then check..

Comment: OK, I ran the two commands in the second, unplugged usb, the pages won't load.... so i had to return to first command (echo - e) and plug usb again, it seems broadcom won works properly :/

Comment: Your built-in adapter can be faulty..are you sure it is ok?

Comment: Not sure, but i connect well with the same built-in directly to same router (without repeater or access point) and sometimes also in the same laptop with Windows8 (in another partition).

Comment: Ok, unplug the USB..run the second potion (don't run the first portion), now run `ifconfig`..

Comment: Ok, details of ifconfig output added to the first question,

Comment: nslookup gmail.com   returns
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Now run the 3rd and 4th commands (`sudo nmcli....`) and check browsing again

Comment: Ok. I unplugged usb -->>run 2 portion ->>conected with broadcom built-in (won't load pages) ->> run the 3 & 4 (the same, can't browse)

Comment: Run this `echo "8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head && sudo service network-manager restart`....try browsing

Comment: Nope I can't Browse(the same, pages won load), it seems combination of [Broadcom built-in + repeater or access point] giving me problems, now can browse well with the first code (echo -e) and ralink usb adapter.

Comment: Don't change anything..do `nslookup gmail.com`

Comment: nslookup gmail.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Now i am sure that there is something wrong with the intermediate devices i.e. access point/router, the traffic is not passing beyond that....may be a configuration or a firewall issue..

Comment: Oooops..there was typo in the last command..run the follow commands: `sudo sed -i '/8.8.8.8/d' /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`, then `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
&& sudo service resolvconf restart`

Comment: No :( , the same(;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached), thanks for all the patience, i don't know if i had to restore my defaults or something (to work with the broadcom built-in, in another room close to router without access points).

Comment: As you can use via the router then there must be something wrong with the configuration of the access point..check that..also do `sudo sed -i '/8.8.8.8/d' /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head && sudo service resolvconf restart` to overwrite the last command..

Answer (score 0):

Two weeks later. but i solved the problem :).

If anyone faces the same problem, or similar.

I deactivated the privative broadcom drivers and restarted ubuntu, apparently the default kernel drivers seems more useful in this case, i've been using the privative drivers for broadcom because the driver aplication in the system settings sugested me to upgrade to privative.

So, only back to default broadcom drivers and it works with routers & acces points in my home & school.